# How is routes file type-checked in Playframework?

Tags: scala, types, playframework

I am thinking about mimicking the same technique which is used to implement the routes file in Play framework (i.e. statically type checked) to create my own DSL for a complicated configuration (to replace yamls).

I have checked out the Play code from github but I was unable to find my way around it. I have found and looking at the class:

```
 play.routes.compiler.RoutesFileParser
```

But still not sure how it links into the bigger picture (e.g: How does it hook into controllers?)

I need to know how this is done in Play's routes file please. Are there any good resources out there for creating DSLs in Scala?